# Show that if each $X_k$ is open in $X,$ then $X$ is simply connected.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am having difficulty with the following Qualifying exam problem.  I am not sure what to use.  Was wondering if there was an algebraic topology approach, or if there was something that I could use from point set topology

A space $X = \cup^\infty_{k = 1}X_k$, where each $X_k$ is a simply connected subset of
$X,$ and $X_k \subseteq X_{k+1},$ for each $k \geq 1.$

Show that if each $X_k$ is open in $X,$ then $X$ is simply connected.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $\gamma\colon S^1\to X$ is continuous, then the image is compact, hence covered by only finitely many of the open $X_k$ and hence by a single $X_k$, in which $\gamma$ can be contracted.